# Howto change (syslog) log target in Postfix (3) for docker usage

Tags: logging, docker, postfix-mta, syslog

I'm creating a fully featured Mailserver completely with docker containers and I want to follow the docker philosophy of having only one process per running container.

Therefore I have among others one container for running only postfix. But since postfix is sending logs only to syslog there is a problem. I was searching a configuration option to change this but it seems that it is not possible to change the log target. I also searched for something in the sources of postfix but didn't find something.

My plan is to have one container only running syslog for all other containers and now I'm searching for a possibility to make postfix send its logs to this other container maybe with a little redirection process. But before I start with this I wanted to ask if someone else already discovered this problem.

Kind regards,
Konstantin

Answer (score 0):

Having syslog in the container is not against the docker philosophy. However, having centralized logging is nice.

Have you considered [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/) instead - which will allow for remote logging?

Comment: Of course I'll not use the old syslog. Haven't decided wether to use syslog-ng or rsyslog. But still: I need to configure postfix so it doesn't send logs to the local but the remote syslog daemon.

Comment: No; you configure the logging daemon and leave Postfix alone.